# Can't get multiple SQL WITH statements to work with Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am trying to get multiple WITH statements to work with Azure SQL database, and according to all I found online, this syntax should work, but I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

SQL:

```
WITH EpicBenefitsData1 ("Epic Benefits Field Name", "Epic Benefits Field Value", "FK Epic ID") AS 
(
    SELECT 
        "Epic Benefits Field Name", "Epic Benefits Field Value", "FK Epic ID"
    FROM 
        [current_dw].[Epic Benefits] AS EpicBenefits1 
    WHERE 
        EpicBenefits1.[Epic Benefits Field Set Name] = 'Default'
),
EpicBenefitsData2 ("Epic Benefits Field Name", "Epic Benefits Field Value", "FK Epic ID") AS 
(
    SELECT 
        "Epic Benefits Field Name", "Epic Benefits Field Value", "FK Epic ID"
    FROM 
        [current_dw].[Epic Benefits] AS EpicBenefits2 
    WHERE 
        EpicBenefits2.[Epic Benefits Field Set Name] = 'FOOBAR'
)
```

The error is on the ")" on the last line.

I've tried many different ways, trying UNION between the two, multiple WITHs and not, omitting the first 3 parameters and not, but I always get this error in Azure Data Studio.

Any help would be appreciated. I need to use a PIVOT on the data later, but this part has to work first.

Tried many different variants of WITH syntax, with no luck.

Comment: As CTE (the WITH factoring clause) is a *newer* way of using **subqueries**, how about moving them (the CTEs) into the subquery form, so that you could use result they return as inline views and - hopefully - build the rest of query on that?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using your CTE.

A CTE on its own is not a valid query, you need to actually `select` data from your CTE.

```
with EpicBenefitsData1....
...
select * from EpicBenefitsData1;
```

Comment: Oh, wow, wouldn't have thought that would be the issue.  I added that simple SELECT and the problem went away and returned some results.  Thanks for the help Stu, that gets me over this hump.